# ContentVersion custom field permissions

Tags: permissions, profile, contentversion

I have added a custom field to my ContentVersion standard object.

Community users are uploading files, but I do not want them to be able to view or edit the new custom field.

I cannot find where do I set  `ContentVersion` fields permissions on my community profile, is there a way to do that

Comment: What is license type of customer community profile?

Comment: customer community login license

Comment: I'm afraid of this license does not have access of ContentVersion...

Comment: but I have access - it depends on the access of the parent record. the problem is - I do not want to give access to all fields

Comment: Ok...got it....you are using as file not as Library....

Comment: Did you try using dedicated page layout for that profile and remove that field from layout....?

Comment: @Ayub this is a good workaround, but I prefer preventing access for the fields on the permissions level, If this is not possible - I will use your suggestion

Comment: Did you ever find out where this is set? still not seeing it in 2021

Comment: @zaitsman - I did not find any way to do that, but I did not check if there is any change today

Comment: I was looking at the same thing and as per documentation, ContentVersion object does not support Field Level Security.

"Note that ContentVersion object does not support Field Level Security and all custom fields are available to all users of a profile. "

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=000380808&type=1